# Connect to shared folder from one Windows Server 2012 to another

Tags: windows-server-2012, shared-folders

I am not sure where I make mistake. I have two almost identical Windows Servers 2012 R2 installations - servers A and B. One server A, I have setup a shared folder. I have verified that I can connect to this share folder from my Windows 10 using UNC path \\IP\Name. I can see files a folders, read them ...

However, if I want to do the same from server B, it always fails. When I try "net use \\IP" or "net use \\IP\Name" on server B, where IP is address of A, I get:

```
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

If I do the same on my Windows 10 desktop, I get success and can work with the share folder and map it.

And I am not sure what I have not tried yet, but I have checked these:

1) network connection properties of server B, if server B has enabled Client for Microsoft Networks - yes; if server B has enabled File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks - yes

2) I have tried advanced properties of IPv4 -> WINS tab -> Enable NETBIOS over TCP/IP (made no difference to default, both A and B have static IPv4)

3) enabling Network discovery and allowing its firewall rules in firewall.cpl + same for File and Printer Sharing and their rules; again made no difference

What am I missing. How can I access shared folder from Windows Server 2012 R2 acting as client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several different machines I have realized that

**my hosting is OVH and they block outgoing connections to ports 139 and 445**

If this is also your case, use IPv6, they do not block it and it works. If you are having problems with new Cloud 2016 VPS - they do not have IPv6 at all, use https://www.tunnelbroker.net/ to get IPv6 connectivity.